# error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure(35)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We have online shopping site. When I am going to checkout page i am getting a error like this "error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure(35)"

From the apache error log i can see some attempts to connect to api.paypal.com. Here is the part of my apache error log

```
* About to connect() to api.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 66.211.168.123... * connected
* Connected to api.paypal.com (66.211.168.123) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection #0
```

When i tried to connect to api.paypal.com using curl i am getting a error like this

```
curl -iv https://api.paypal.com/
* About to connect() to api.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 66.211.168.91... connected
* Connected to api.paypal.com (66.211.168.91) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Answer (score 4):

`openssl s_client` does a better job of explaining what's going on here since it gives whether it's receiving or sending these messages. api.paypal.com is requesting a specific client certificate (this is the `* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13)` line curl is printing) and you're sending the wrong (or no) certificate, so your connection fails:

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:failed in SSLv3 read finished A
6016:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1086:SSL alert number 40
6016:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
```

Googling for paypal api info, it appears that you'll need to request a [client certificate for the API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/apicertificates). They also have a username/password "signature" option, but this option [uses a completely different server](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview#id09C2F0N0TNW).  If you have these, then configuring your cart software to use them is an issue to take up with the cart developer.  If you *are* the developer and you have a certificate, see the --cert, --cert-type, --key, and --key-type flags to `curl` to configure the cert and private key curl uses.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The issue has been resolved now. The issue was one of our developer wrongly configured the Paypal API endpoint as api.paypal.com. It should be api-3t.paypal.com to work correctly.

Comment: Note that these answers are obsolete. SSLv3 is not supported due to the POODLE vulnerability. Using it could generate an error like this. See [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379773/paypal-ipn-acknowledgements-failing-with-ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytessslv3-aler/26380523#26380523)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me on a CentOS 8 system was checking the System Cryptography Policy by verifying the **/etc/crypto-policies/config** reads the default value of **DEFAULT** rather than any other value.

Once changing this value to **DEFAULT**, run the following command:

```
/usr/bin/update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT
```

Rerun the curl command and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I meet this same question.

Because I din't open 443 port in Centos.

So you checkout the 443 port!

> sudo losf -i tcp:443

Resolve method:

cd /etc/httpd/conf.d vim ssl.conf

in the first line add two lines:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443
```

You can try it!